# How to test async function with spyOn?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test an async function in a react native app.

```
class myClass extends React.Component {

  ...

  closeModal = async () => {

    if (someCondition) {
      await myFunction1();
    } else {
      await myFunction2();
    }

    this.props.navigation.state.params.onGoBack();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
  };

  ...

}
```

This is my test:

```
const navigation = {
  navigate: jest.fn(),
  state: { params: { onGoBack: jest.fn() } },
};

const renderComponent = overrides => {
  props = {
    navigation,
    ...overrides,
  };

  return shallow(< myClass.wrappedComponent {...props} />);
};


describe('When the user presses the close icon', () => {
    it('should close the modal', () => {
      const wrapper = renderComponent();
      const instance = wrapper.instance();
      const spyCloseModal = jest.spyOn(instance, 'closeModal');
      instance().forceUpdate();
      component
        .find({ testID: 'close-icon' })
        .props()
        .onPress();
      expect(spyCloseModal).toHaveBeenCalled(); // this is passed
      expect(navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled(); // this is not passed
    });
});
```

It looks like it gets stuck on the await calls. If I remove the await calls then it passes. Someone mentioned in another post to use `.and.callThrough` after spyOn but it gives me this error

> Cannot read property 'callThrough' of undefined

Answer (score 7):

one of solution is to make your test `async` and run `await (anything)` to split your test into several microtasks:

```
it('should close the modal', async () => {
      const wrapper = renderComponent();
      component
        .find({ testID: 'close-icon' })
        .props()
        .onPress();
      await Promise.resolve();
      expect(navigation.state.params.onGoBack).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
      expect(navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Main");
    });
```

I believe you don't need either `.forceUpdate` nor `.spyOn` on instance method. once navigation happens properly it does not matter by what internal method it has been called

more on microtask vs macrotask: https://abc.danch.me/microtasks-macrotasks-more-on-the-event-loop-881557d7af6f

alternative is to use macrotask(`setTimeout(...., 0)`)

```
it('should close the modal', (done) => {
      const wrapper = renderComponent();
      component
        .find({ testID: 'close-icon' })
        .props()
        .onPress();
      setTimeout(() => {
        expect(navigation.state.params.onGoBack).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
        expect(navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Main");
        done();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're on the right track...the issue is that `closeModal` is asynchronous.

The `await` hasn't finished by the time execution returns to the test so `this.props.navigation.navigate` hasn't been called yet.

The test needs to wait for `closeModal` to complete before asserting that `navigate` has been called.

`closeModal` is an `async` function so it will return a `Promise`...

...and you can use the spy to retrieve the `Promise` it returns...

...then you can call `await` on that `Promise` in your test to make sure `closeModal` has completed before asserting that `navigate` has been called.

Here is a simplified working example to get you started:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

class MyClass extends React.Component {
  closeModal = async () => {
    await Promise.resolve();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
  }
  render() { return <div onClick={() => this.closeModal()}></div> }
}

test('MyClass', async () => {  // <= async test function
  const props = { navigation: { navigate: jest.fn() }};
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyClass {...props} />);
  const instance = wrapper.instance();
  const spyCloseModal = jest.spyOn(instance, 'closeModal');
  wrapper.find('div').simulate('click');
  expect(spyCloseModal).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
  const promise = spyCloseModal.mock.results[0].value;  // <= get the Promise returned by closeModal
  await promise;  // <= await the Promise
  expect(props.navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
})
```

Note the use of [`mockFn.mock.results`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresults) to get the `Promise` returned by `closeModal`.

Answer (score 0):

```
it('myFunction', async ()=> {
    spyOn(object, 'myFunction').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('mockedResult'));
    const result = await foo();
    expect(result).toBe('mockedResult');
})
```