# I want to spyOn method, return value, and continue running through the script

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, axios

I am spying on a method, in this case: `axios.post`. I want to resolve it and continue running the script, because in the `then` block, it has to run another method. The current way I am solving it, is with a `jest.spyOn(axios, 'post').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve( ));`. This, as it says, a mock implementation, and will completely forego the actual code. What I want is a way to resolve this call (by `returnValue` or something) and continue the actual code. I remember `Jasmin` had something to the effect of that.

EDIT:
I seems that the axios promise.resolve is actually progressing it. The problem more lies in that I am trying to mock the `helpers.showResponseMessage` and Jest keeps insisting it does not get called (even when the console.log within the mock gets called). Any ideas?

Contact (Axios call I am trying to resolve properly)

```
const recommendationHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        axios.post('/contact.json', extractData(config.addMessage))
            .then(() => {
                showResponseMessage(`Din besked er sendt.`, initialState, false, setConfig, 5000);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                showResponseMessage(`Der opstod en fejl ved sendning. Prøv igen senere.`, {}, true, setConfig, 10000);
            });
    }
```

Testfile

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure, shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import axios from '../../axios-instances/axios-firebase'
import * as helpers from '../../utility/Helpers/Helpers'
import Contact from './Contact';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('<Contact />', () => {
    it.only('should POST data to server if necessary payload is included', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(axios, 'post').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve( ));
        const wrapper = mount(<Contact />);
        jest.spyOn(helpers, 'showResponseMessage').mockImplementationOnce(_ => console.log('test'));

        wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', {
            preventDefault: () => { }
        });

        expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(helpers.showResponseMessage).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(wrapper.find('#responseMessage')).toHaveLength(1);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow provided, as it always does.

Apparently you need to put in an `await Promise.resolve()` to split it into microtasks. I am not quite sure how it works, and if somebody could explain, it would be great.

Stackoverflow answer: [How to test async function with spyOn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56654870/how-to-test-async-function-with-spyon)

```
describe('<Contact />', () => {
    it.only('should POST data to server if necessary payload is included', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(axios, 'post').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve( ));
        const wrapper = mount(<Contact />);
        jest.spyOn(helpers, 'showResponseMessage').mockImplementationOnce(_ => console.log('test'));

        wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', {
            preventDefault: () => { }
        });

        expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        await Promise.resolve(); <-- THIS IS APPARENTLY A MICROTASK
        expect(helpers.showResponseMessage).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(wrapper.find('#responseMessage')).toHaveLength(1);

    });
});
```

Comment: It works because showResponseMessage is called asynchronously, delayed by a promise length, and you need to do at least the same delay in tests to get on par with it. `await Promise.resolve()` is redundant because `await` does `Promise.resolve` for any value, could be `await null`. A more precise way is to wait for specific promise you're waiting, which is dummy promise that a request returns, i.e. `await axios.post.mock.results[0].value`. This may not work if there are more nested promises in recommendationHandler.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Estus, makes a lot of sense. I will try out your dummy promise, but why is it more precise? I seems that I am not using that results[0].value for anything. Is it purely for semantics and explaining what I am waiting for?

Comment: That's correct. It would make a difference if axios.post weren't mocked but spied, or were mocked to not resolve instantly (network requests are supposed to be mocked in tests, but this is applicable to other async APIs too).