# Jasmine halts after 2nd call to the same async mock function in test function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I suspect Jasmine halts after running an async mocked function 2nd time in the same function, but I cant seem to find the reason or the correct workaround.

The getDialogAnswer is a jquery dialog wrapped in a promise and async await function.
This is an implementaiton of "delete" + "are you sure" dialog boxes.
Everything works as expected in the running application.

the 2 calls

```
let optiontext = 'Delete project from plan?'
let deleteProject = await getDialogAnswer(title, optiontext, choices, defaultvalue)
...
optiontext = 'REALLY delete project from plan???<br>There is no going back'
deleteProject =  await getDialogAnswer(title, optiontext, choices, defaultvalue)
```

The mock function

```
const getDialogAnswer = jasmine.createSpy('Mock_getDialogAnswer').and.returnValues('yes','yes');
```

The test function is created with async

```
it("should delete on yes + yes", async () => {
```

This passes

```
expect(getDialogAnswer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
```

but following 4 of this type fails - says called 0 times.

```
expect(mainPart.clearSelected).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

The last I check is

```
expect(unsaved_changes).toBe(true);
```

which reports "Expected null to be true."
But a console output writes correct true, so I know the function finished correctly.

The test is running in Jasmine HTML standalon Specrunner. I have tested with both 4.6,4.6 and 5.0Beta.

If I change the second call

```
deleteProject =  await getDialogAnswer(title, optiontext, choices, defaultvalue)
```

to

```
deleteProject =  'yes'
```

getDialogAnswer is of course only run once,  but the rest of the expectaions pass!

And if I just remove the await of the second call to be like this

```
deleteProject =  getDialogAnswer(title, optiontext, choices, defaultvalue)
```

It all passes test  - but then I cannot delete in the real application! Here the delete is not carried through.

I have gone through all I could find on async and spyes in the doc https://jasmine.github.io/index.html, and tried the method

```
const getDialogAnswer = jasmine.createSpy('Mock_getDialogAnswer').and.returnValues(
    Promise.resolve('yes'),Promise.resolve('yes'));
```

With same result

I have searched here, but mainly found how to setup test functions.
I have a suspecion that I may have setup my mock fucntion incorrect or that Jasmine maybe has a flaw here.
But I cant find any documentaion or other thread that shed some light on this.
This might be a lead, but it seems to me that I am already doing it right.
[How to test async function with spyOn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56654870/how-to-test-async-function-with-spyon)
Or am I missing something tiny but essential?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue myself.

The culprit was "missing" async/await keywords in application code. Not needed for function but for test only!

By posting the question I apparently set some thoughts in motion! It sometimes help solving an issue by stating and explaining it to others!

- Jasmine works flawlessly (at least in this matter)
- My test case works correct (with the addition of returning resolved promise)

This is the boiled down and scrambled original code, which works in the application, but not in test:
I have had to insert the async block in the original object method, to make the 2 async/promise dialog calls work (And yes, messy and ripe for refactoring!)

```
    function main_obj() {
    this.objmethod1 = function () {
        const async_objmethod = async function(){
            let deleteProject = await getDialogAnswer()
            deleteProject = await getDialogAnswer()
            this.objmethod2();
            this.objmethod3()
            this.objmethod4();
            unsaved_changes = true;
            method5(this.name);
        }
        async_objmethod.bind(this)();
    };
    this.objmethod2 = function () {};
    this.objmethod3 = function () {};
    this.objmethod4 = function () {};
}
```

By adding async + await the test runs and passes as intended and expected

```
    this.objmethod1 = async function () {
        ...
        await async_objmethod.bind(this)();
    };
```

In the application, there is no need to wait for the function to finish, but to test it properly it was needed.

I have included working specrunner html, code + testcode for completenes

specrunner.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="jasmine_lib/jasmine-5.0.0-beta.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jasmine_lib/jasmine-5.0.0-beta.0/jasmine.css">
  <script src="jasmine_lib/jasmine-5.0.0-beta.0/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="jasmine_lib/jasmine-5.0.0-beta.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="jasmine_lib/jasmine-5.0.0-beta.0/boot0.js"></script>
  <script src="jasmine_lib/jasmine-5.0.0-beta.0/boot1.js"></script>

  <script src="maincode2.js" > </script> 
  <script src="test_spec.js"></script>

</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

maincode.js

```
function main_obj() {
    this.objmethod1 = async function () {
        const async_objmethod = async function(){
            let deleteProject = await getDialogAnswer()
            deleteProject = await getDialogAnswer()
            this.objmethod2();
            this.objmethod3()
            this.objmethod4();
            unsaved_changes = true;
            method5(this.name);
        }
        await async_objmethod.bind(this)();
    };
    this.objmethod2 = function () {};
    this.objmethod3 = function () {};
    this.objmethod4 = function () {};
}
```

test_spec.js

```
const getDialogAnswer = jasmine.createSpy('Mock_getDialogAnswer').and.returnValue(
    Promise.resolve('yes'),
    Promise.resolve('yes'),
);
const method5 = jasmine.createSpy('Mock_method5')
let unsaved_changes;

// var for main_inst instance set in 'before-funcs'
let main_inst
beforeEach(function() {
    main_inst = new main_obj();
    unsaved_changes = null
    spyOn(main_inst, 'objmethod2')
    spyOn(main_inst, 'objmethod3')
    spyOn(main_inst, 'objmethod4')
});

describe("Test makemain_inst.js", () => {
    describe("Test new jquery ui dialog functions", () => {
        describe("test dialog uses", () => {
            describe("test this.objmethod1()", () => {
                describe("test yes no", () => {
                    it("should delete on yes + yes", async () => {
                        // ------------ setup -------------
                        // --------   Call ----------------
                        const x = await main_inst.objmethod1()
                        // ------------- verify ------------
                        expect(getDialogAnswer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)

                        expect(main_inst.objmethod2).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
                        expect(main_inst.objmethod3).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
                        expect(main_inst.objmethod4).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
                        expect(method5).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
                        expect(unsaved_changes).toBe(true);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```